# $wpdb>update having no effect on database?

Tags: php, database, wordpress

I am trying to update a meta_value in the database for a specific meta_id using the **$wpdb>update** function but it doesn't change anything when its executed.

Here is the code.

```
<?php

// ID = 10074

global $wpdb;
$meta_value = 'NEW_VALUE';
$meta_key = 'wpcf-vehicle-status';
$meta_id = '10074';

$wpdb->update( 

 'wp25_postmeta', 
    array( 
     'meta_value' => $meta_value,
     'meta_key' => $meta_key
     ),
   array( 'ID' => $meta_id )

   );

   ?>
```

Any advice or help would be much appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Are you sure `$wpdb` is defined?

Comment: @u_mulder if not the method call should trigger an error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are couple of issues here:

1) There is no field "ID" in "wp_postmeta" table. It should be "meta_id" OR "post_id".
2) Table name should be in this format:

```
$wpdb->prefix."postmeta"
```

**Here's the code after fixing TWO issues:**

```
<?php

// ID = 10074

global $wpdb;
$meta_value = 'NEW_VALUE';
$meta_key = 'wpcf-vehicle-status';
$meta_id = '10074';

$wpdb->update( 

    $wpdb->prefix."postmeta", 
    array( 
        'meta_value' => $meta_value,
        'meta_key' => $meta_key
    ),
    array( 'meta_id' => $meta_id )

);

?>
```

Comment: How would you update the meta_id if you didn't know it but you know the post_id and the meta_key value ? 

The columns in the database are

    meta_id    =  10074
    post_id    = 852
    meta_key    =  wpcf-vehicle-status
    meta_value   = SOLD


I can see the original answer is not targeting that specific post_id and updating all rows in the database, I assume a WHERE clause would be required ? so if the post_id = 852 and the meta_key = wpcf-vehicle-status then update that specific meta_id only.

Comment: Question above used var like meta_id, that's the reason showing meta_id in the updated code which is possible but not ideal.
I have also mentioned in the answer that they can use post_id which is ideal.

Answer (score 0):

I have found another function called ' update_post_meta ' which seems to be working. Thanks for you input.